# firefox issue, proxysettingsperuser stucked in 0. malware?

Tags: windows-7, windows, firefox, windows-registry

I'm having this issue with my Windows 7 installation since a while ago, maybe it's because of a virus, I don't know for sure. The thing is, that the value of the registry key `proxysettingsperuser` is always on 0, this leads to Firefox to refuse web certificates on every single website and I can't browse the web. Every time I change it manually to "1" it always goes back to zero when I restart the computer and it's a cumbersome to always have to go to the registry to change it back to 1 so I can browse normally with Firefox. Is there a service or a program or another registry key doing this thing??? did I catch a virus or something??
these are the particular keys that I'm talking about

```
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings]
"ProxySettingsPerUser"=dword:00000000

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings]
"ProxySettingsPerUser"=dword:00000000
```

Any suggestions?

edit: These keys makes me unable to change the proxy settings in the control panel and make browsers to act weird. I've never made any changes to the proxy configuration, and I'm certainly the admin of this machine.

Screencap:
http://s12.postimg.org/jzz8wus71/Picture_2015_08_14_20_09_12.png

Comment: IE is OK, right?

Comment: yeah IE is ok but strangely when I end up with a wrong link I don't get the usual 404 error page I get this cryptic DNS related message that's in the image I attached (and it also appears on Firefox).This might be related to that proxysettingsperuser value too.

Comment: So IE does not have this (the DNS error) problem? If IE is also NG, maybe your DNS server settings changed? Can you connect without the proxy server?

Answer (score 0):

First, uninstall Firefox. Then, use [CCleaner](https://www.piriform.com/ccleaner) to clean your registry. Restart your computer, and reinstall Firefox. This should fix any issues with Firefox.

You also should reset your internet settings as described [here](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/refresh-firefox-reset-add-ons-and-settings).

Comment: Not sure whether registry cleaning would fix this issue. Reinstalling Firefox might help, but the user may need to create a new profile.

Comment: @DragonLord It might not do anything, but it often helps, and he is having issues with his registry.